# NGINX redirect to docker containers

Tags: nginx

I have a CentOS server running docker with 3 containers and NGINX. The open ports are 80, 443, and 22. The containers have ports like so:

- container A: 9000
- container B: 4201
- container C: 5443

Each of the NGINX configuration files are nearly identical:

```
/etc/nginx/conf.d/A.conf

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name A.local;
    return 301 https://A.local$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name A.local;

    ssl_certificate ...;
    ssl_certificate_key ...;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

The only things that change between the files is A to B, A to C, and port number after 127.0.0.1.

Now when I browse to A.local (this is in /etc/hosts on my local machine) I get a self signed ssl, I accept, I get the correct website! A works!

Browse to B.local, I get a self signed ssl, I accept, I get 502 bad gateway...

Browse to C.local, I get a self signed ssl, I accept, I get 502 bad gateway...

When I go to 192.168.1.247:4201 I get the correct website, the container is running correctly, I am able to access it directly, nginx is not passing me through properly.

**EDIT** Additional info:

*docker ps*

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                                                 NAMES
047f31019eb9        gitlab/gitlab-ce      "/assets/wrapper"        6 hours ago         Up 6 hours (healthy)    80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5522->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5443->80/tcp    gitlab
7ffe8b06b16b        crate                 "/docker-entrypoin..."   26 hours ago        Up 26 hours (healthy)   4300/tcp, 5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4201->4200/tcp            crate-01
f82437f328de        portainer/portainer   "/portainer"             2 days ago          Up 2 days               0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp                                portainer
```

*sudo nginx -T*

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}


# configuration file /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-geoip.conf:
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so";

# configuration file /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so";

# configuration file /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-perl.conf:
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_perl_module.so";

# configuration file /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so";

# configuration file /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-mail.conf:
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_mail_module.so";

# configuration file /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-stream.conf:
load_module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so";

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/A.local.conf:
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name A.local;
    return 301 https://A.local$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name A.local;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/www/A.local/A.local.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/www/A.local/A.local.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/B.local.conf:
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name B.local;
    return 301 https://B.local$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name B.local;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/www/B.local/B.local.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/www/B.local/B.local.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5443;
    }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/C.local.conf:
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name C.local;
    return 301 https://C.local$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name C.local;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/www/C.local/C.local.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/www/C.local/C.local.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4201;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `docker ps`? Did you confirm via `nginx -T` that everything is running as excepted in `nginx`?

Comment: in the output of nginx -T that you posted, all proxy_pass point to proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4201;
There is no port 9000 or 5443.

Comment: @LucaG Thats a typo in my question here, I fixed it. `nginx -T`'s output shows they are different ports.

Comment: if you do 

    wget -q -O- http://127.0.0.1:4201 

on the same host running nginx, do you get an error or the correct output?

Comment: @lucaG, 9000 gets me the HTML I expect, 4201 gives me a JSON on the running crate container, and 5443 gives me the HTML I expect. The JSON is a bit odd, since accessing it via my browser gets me the expected interface, but, it appears to be working.

Comment: please add error_log /var/log/vhost_A.log to the server block for A, vhost_B.log to the server block for B, and so on. Restart nginx and trigger the 502 error. Is the error logged in the proper file? What's the exact error msg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think SELinux might be preventing nginx from opening a connection to 127.0.0.1:5443. Try disabling SELinux or allow nginx to open a connection to any port with:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect true
```

Comment: Yea, the error logs I was just reading were giving permission errors for the other ports. And yes, the `setsebool` command fixed the ports. So that's one problem. But now that weird bug that disappeared has reappeared... Attempting to go to B.local redirects to C.local... At least I can access 2/3 of my server nicely.

Comment: You just saved my sanity.